# Blazor EditForm Validation not working when using Child Component

Tags: validation, blazor

I have a Blazor component called EditOffice. It looks as follows:

```
<EditForm Model="@Office" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">

    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputTextRow Label="Name" @bind-Value="@Office.Name" Placeholder="Enter name" />
    <InputTextRow Label="ABN" @bind-Value="@Office.ABN" Placeholder="Enter ABN" />
...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary edit-btn">Save office</button>
</EditForm>
```

I created child components called InputTextRow in an attempt to *Tidy* my code. They look as follows:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="@Id" class="col-sm-3">@Label: </label>
    <InputText id="@Id" @oninput="OnValueChanged" @bind-Value="@Value" class="form-control col-sm-8" placeholder="@Placeholder"></InputText>
    <ValidationMessage class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-8" For="@(() => Value)" />
</div>

@code {

    public string Id => Label.ToLower().Replace(" ", "");

    [Parameter]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Placeholder { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = e.Value.ToString();
        return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }
}
```

The ValidationMessage doesn't work when in my child component. Any idea why?

Answer (score 15):

I know I'm a little late but here is my answer :)

So there is better solution right now.

### TL:DR Solution for lazy ones

Be advised - it's **experimental**, but package is already in release candidate so no worries I guess.

Use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation) package and `<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />` instead of `<DataAnnotationsValidator />` and use this thingy:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class YourComplexModel
{
    // other properties

    [ValidateComplexType] // <--life saver
    public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; } = new ChildModel();
}
```

### Fragment from MS Docs

Link [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types):

> Blazor provides support for validating form input using data annotations with the built-in DataAnnotationsValidator. However, the DataAnnotationsValidator only validates top-level properties of the model bound to the form that aren't collection- or complex-type properties.

> To validate the bound model's entire object graph, including collection- and complex-type properties, use the ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator provided by the experimental [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation) package:

```cs
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    ...
</EditForm>
```

> Annotate model properties with [ValidateComplexType]. In the following model classes, the ShipDescription class contains additional data annotations to validate when the model is bound to the form:

`Starship.cs:`

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Starship
{
    ...

    [ValidateComplexType]
    public ShipDescription ShipDescription { get; set; } = 
        new ShipDescription();

    ...
}
```

`ShipDescription.cs:`

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ShipDescription
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Description too long (40 char).")]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(240, ErrorMessage = "Description too long (240 char).")]
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This does not exist today, any other valid solution at this date?

Comment: Hi @LiviuMihaianu. Sadly I didn't worked with Blazor for a while already. As far as I'm concerned - it did worked even for RC versions of .NET 5, but maybe something did indeed changed. I would check if there is some kind of change in namespaces in recent MS blogs.

Other than that - maybe check out [Fluent validation for Blazor](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/blazor.html) if built-in solution doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @RafałKopczyński, did you have a chance to check it out? the linked nuget package cannot be found from vs or the PM Console

Comment: The package exists, but it is marked as prerelease. You need to enable **Include prerelease** in NuGet to see it. The package hasn't been updated in quite a while, but I tested it and it still works with .NET 6 & Blazor.

Comment: Thanks!  The combination of `<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />` and `[ValidateComplexType]` did the trick for me, to validate a list of objects.

Comment: Works. The [ValidateComplexType] annotated properties need to be public as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same issue. My code is very similar to yours. My child component do validate, but the validation error message is not displayed.

I do use this extension method:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TimeRecording.Extensions
{
    public static class EditContextExtensions
    {
        static PropertyInfo IsModifiedProperty;
        static MethodInfo GetFieldStateMethod;

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates an entire object tree
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="editContext">The EditContext to validate the Model of</param>
        /// <returns>True if valid, otherwise false</returns>
        public static bool ValidateObjectTree(this EditContext editContext)
        {
            var validatedObjects = new HashSet<object>();
            ValidateObject(editContext, editContext.Model, validatedObjects);
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            return !editContext.GetValidationMessages().Any();
        }

        public static void ValidateProperty(this EditContext editContext, FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
        {
            if (fieldIdentifier.Model == null)
                return;

            var propertyInfo = fieldIdentifier.Model.GetType().GetProperty(
                fieldIdentifier.FieldName,
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

            var validatedObjects = new HashSet<object>();
            ValidateProperty(editContext, fieldIdentifier.Model, propertyInfo, validatedObjects);
        }

        private static void ValidateObject(
            EditContext editContext,
            object instance,
            HashSet<object> validatedObjects)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                return;

            if (validatedObjects.Contains(instance))
                return;

            if (instance is IEnumerable && !(instance is string))
            {
                foreach (object value in (IEnumerable)instance)
                    ValidateObject(editContext, value, validatedObjects);
                return;
            }

            if (instance.GetType().Assembly == typeof(string).Assembly)
                return;

            validatedObjects.Add(instance);

            var properties = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                ValidateProperty(editContext, instance, property, validatedObjects);
        }

        private static void ValidateProperty(
            EditContext editContext,
            object instance,
            PropertyInfo property,
            HashSet<object> validatedObjects)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged(editContext, instance, property.Name);

            object value = property.GetValue(instance);
            ValidateObject(editContext, value, validatedObjects);
        }

        private static void NotifyPropertyChanged(
            EditContext editContext,
            object instance,
            string propertyName)
        {
            if (GetFieldStateMethod == null)
            {
                GetFieldStateMethod = editContext.GetType().GetMethod(
                    "GetFieldState",
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            }

            var fieldIdentifier = new FieldIdentifier(instance, propertyName);
            object fieldState = GetFieldStateMethod.Invoke(editContext, new object[] { fieldIdentifier, true });

            if (IsModifiedProperty == null)
            {
                IsModifiedProperty = fieldState.GetType().GetProperty(
                    "IsModified",
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            }

            object originalIsModified = IsModifiedProperty.GetValue(fieldState);
            editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);
            IsModifiedProperty.SetValue(fieldState, originalIsModified);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Karl - can you show how you use these extension methods please. I guess `ValidateObjectTree` is synonymous for `editContext.Validate`, i'm unclear how `ValidateProperty` is used by the child component