# DataAnnotationsValidator not working for Composite model in Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, data-annotations, blazor-webassembly

`<DataAnnotationsValidator />` not working for the composite model TradeViewModel I have used in my razor page.
Is there any way to work it out?

Razor code:

```
  <EditForm Model="@TradeViewModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" @onreset="HandleReset">
        <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
       
         <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col">
         <label>Name</label>
                      
         <InputText @bind-Value="@trade.invitedName" class="form-control" />
         <ValidationMessage For="@(() => trade.invitedName)" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col">
         <label>Email</label>              
         <InputText @bind-Value="@trade.invitedEmail" class="form-control" />
         <ValidationMessage For="@(() => trade.invitedEmail)" />
         </div>
         </div>
 </EditForm>
```

suppose inviteName & invitedEmail are in different models.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
      public class ModelA
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "The  Name is mandatory")]
            public string invitedName { get; set; }
        }
    
     public class ModelB
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "The  Email is mandatory")]
            public string invitedEmail { get; set; }
        }
```

Composite model:

```
    public class TradeViewModel
    {
            [ValidateComplexType]
            public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
            [ValidateComplexType]
            public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried using ValidateComplex type method, but it's not recognized in my code. Packages installed. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation`
[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me when I installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DataAnnotations.Validation` package correctly into the project.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DataAnnotations.Validation` is deprecated

Comment: This package is depricated, I'll have to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

For the complex model, instead of `<DataAnnotationsValidator />` use `<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />`

So, the code goes below

```
<EditForm Model="@TradeViewModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" @onreset="HandleReset">
   <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator /> // modify this line <DataAnnotationsValidator />
   
     <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col">
     <label>Name</label>
                  
     <InputText @bind-Value="@trade.invitedName" class="form-control" />
     <ValidationMessage For="@(() => trade.invitedName)" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col">
     <label>Email</label>              
     <InputText @bind-Value="@trade.invitedEmail" class="form-control" />
     <ValidationMessage For="@(() => trade.invitedEmail)" />
     </div>
     </div>
 </EditForm>
```

Comment: I tried <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />  with adding ValidateComplexTypes in model but it doesn't work. Which is the exact package need to be included?

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DataAnnotations.Validation` is the package to be added

Comment: CHECK these links [LINK1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types), [LINK2](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/validating-complex-models-in-blazor/), [LINK3](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/form/validation#validate-a-complex-model)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I really liked Validating complex type. But my code is not recognizing validatecomplextype even after package installed. Please check my edited question.

Comment: Check this work-around solution [SOLUTION1](https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/) $ [LINK2](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation) for the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue, and I find a solution using

`[ValidateComplexType]` attribute a the child property level and with the `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` component.

as state in the post
[Blazor EditForm Validation not working when using Child Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60519482/blazor-editform-validation-not-working-when-using-child-component)

```
public class Starship
{
    ...

    [ValidateComplexType]
    public ShipDescription ShipDescription { get; set; } = 
        new ShipDescription();

    ...
}
```

and

```
   <EditForm Model="@myModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">

        <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator/>
        <ValidationSummary />
```